# Sending emails using nodemailer in node.js

Tags: node.js, email, ssl, openssl, nodemailer

I've got an authorisation problem while sending emails via my own email address. Here is my code:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'serverDomain',
    port: 25,
    secure: 'false',
    tls: {ciphers: "SSLv3"},
    auth: {
        user: 'myEmailAddress',
        pass: 'myPassword'
    }
});

transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'myEmailAddress',
    to: 'someAddress',
    subject: 'Subject',
    html: 'Some HTML code here'
}, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

And the error is as follows:

> { [Error: Invalid login: 535 authorization failed (#5.7.0)]
>     code: 'EAUTH',
>     response: '535 authorization failed (#5.7.0)',
>     responseCode: 535 }

I'm sure the credentials are correct. I get  the same error also on ports 465 and 587.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Most probably because you try to connect with outdated SSLv3. Its disabled everywhere so why are you trying to use it?

Comment: Are you sure the port is correct? 25?

Comment: I tried also 465 and 587. All of them give the same error.
@migg without it I get the same error

Comment: So if you are sure the connection to the server is not the problem, then your server seems to be pretty sure that your credentials are incorrect. Did you try sending the mail directly on the server with the credentials?

Answer (score 0):

This can be issue with giving access rights in your email account. So can you make sure those setups you did properly.

1. Need to **Allow Less Secure Apps** in case of using Gmail service
2. If you are using **2FA** in that case you would have to create an Application specific password. Because your normal password wont work.